# Multiply index by 2 within for each loop

Tags: c#

I want to display the double number of checkboxes based on Count items in Model.Trucks.Items.

For now, the current `foreach` loop is returning me the `Count` of `Model.Trucks.Items` to 2 and hence 2 checkboxes are displayed. I want to display 7 checkboxes if there are 2 items. 
Can anyone please help me on how to achieve this ?

```
<ul>
    @{ int i = 1; }
    @foreach (var item in Model.Trucks.Items)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" checked id="@i">               
        </li>

        i++;
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe add another `<li>` element ? Also what if there are 3 items or more? Should it contain 6 checkboxes or still 4 ?

Comment: @Fabjan : The question is edited.

Comment: @jones :- what is the actual requirement? what if there 3 items? and when 4?

Comment: There will be no 3 items. The count in the list will always be even.

Comment: What exactly are your requirements though? Now you need 7 checkboxes if there are 2 items, but what if there are 4 items? Do you then need 14 checkboxes?

Comment: The list will always contain even number of items.

Comment: So what you mean is that the number of checkboxes needs to be `Items.Count` * 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a `for` loop and specify how many times you want to do it:

```
<ul>
@{ int i = 1; }
@{int multiplier = 7; }
@for(var j = 0; j < multiplier; j++) {
    @foreach (var item in Model.Trucks.Items)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" checked id="@i">               
        </li>

        i++;
    }
}
</ul>
```

here your original `foreach` loop will run however many times you specify in `multiplier`, so if you need it to run 7 times, you can set `multiplier` to 7.

Alternatively, you could just add a second `foreach` (but I wouldn't recommend this), or as mentioned in the comments, just add however many `<li>` you need on each iteration:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Trucks.Items)
{
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="@i">               
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="@i">               
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="@i">               
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="@i">               
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="@i">               
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="@i">               
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="@i">               
    </li>

    i++;
}
```